# Python unresolved import requests

Tags: python, python-requests

I have a very frustrating problem. I want to run this simple script but I can't because `requests` is not installed but it is. I am using Visual Studio 2019 and I have no clue about Python. Normally I am programming with C#.

```
from pprint import pprint
import requests

URL = 'https://discosweb.esoc.esa.int'
token = '<token>'

response = requests.get(
    f'{URL}/api/objects',
    headers={
        'Authorization': f'Bearer {token}',
        'DiscosWeb-Api-Version': '2',
    },
    params={
        'filter': "eq(objectClass,Payload)&gt(reentry.epoch,epoch:'2020-01-01')",
        'sort': '-reentry.epoch',
    },
)

doc = response.json()
if response.ok:
    pprint(doc['data'])
else:
    pprint(doc['errors']))
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  This is the "is it plugged in" question.  How do you know that `requests` is installed?

Comment: You may have multiple versions of Python installed, and `requests` may be installed for a different installation

Comment: When I want to install requests for example like so. ``pip install requests`` It tells me that everything is already installed.

Comment: Try running this: pip3 install --upgrade requests

Comment: unfortunatly: **Requirement already staisfied**

Comment: @Alec are you using an environment? Anaconda, venv, etc?
Maybe you forgot to select the correct python interpreter

Comment: I'm not a VS user, but it sounds like it's using a different Python environment than your command line is.

Comment: Try to use IDE PyCharm.

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by the error message, it is natural to suspect that you don't have the [Python package `requests`](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) installed. You might want to take a look at [this Visual Studio tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-05-installing-packages?view=vs-2022) for Python package installation :)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is installed and it is installed as you suggested. Thats why I am puzzleld.

Comment: Thanks @Alec , in that case I think it will be helpful to post a few screenshots of your environment in Visual Studio, to help us understand your current settings, if you don't mind.

Comment: Hello again. It is the day after I posted this question and the restart made it work I dont know how but it did. Would it help others if I still post a Screenshot or do you think the problem is too unique?